# How to show "product description" in the online shopping website?

Tags: php, mysql

I try to show the **product description** in the online shopping. But it show me error, other product details can show in the oline shopping.

Below is my coding:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$product_id = $row['product_id'];
$product_sku = $row['sku'];
$product_name = $row['prdNm'];
$product_price = $row['product_price'];
$product_category_name = $row['category_name'];
$product_weight = $row['weight'];
$product_image = $row['image'];
// $product_description = $row['description'];//
$product_price = $row['price'];
$product_shipment_type = $row['shipment_type'];
$product_warranty = $row['warranty'];
$product_short_description = $row['short_description'];

}

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.11street.my/rest/prodservices/product",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" 
standalone=\"yes\"?>
<Product>
<selMthdCd>01</selMthdCd>
<dispCtgrNo>4932</dispCtgrNo>
<prdTypCd>01</prdTypCd>
<prdNm>$product_name</prdNm>
<prdStatCd>01</prdStatCd>
<prdWght>$product_weight</prdWght>
<minorSelCnYn>Y</minorSelCnYn>
<prdImage01>$product_image</prdImage01>
//<htmlDetail>$product_description</htmlDetail>//
<advrtStmt>9789792771251</advrtStmt>
<sellerPrdCd>815210</sellerPrdCd>
<selTermUseYn>N</selTermUseYn>
<selPrc>$product_price</selPrc>
<prdSelQty>9999</prdSelQty>
<cuponcheck>Y</cuponcheck>
<dscAmtPercnt>25</dscAmtPercnt>
<cupnDscMthdCd>01</cupnDscMthdCd>
<cupnIssStartDy>13/08/2014</cupnIssStartDy>
<cupnIssEndDy>20/08/2014</cupnIssEndDy>
<cupnUseLmtDyYn>Y</cupnUseLmtDyYn>
<pointYN>Y</pointYN>
<pointValue>100</pointValue>
<spplWyCd>02</spplWyCd>
```

The error is shown in below:

```
Error 400--Bad Request
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.1 400 Bad Request
The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. 
The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.
```

I put the "//"symbol meaning is this  "product description" code can't work. If work it will show me like below sample picture:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MYbs.jpg)
[image]
Hope someone can help me solve this problem and let me know which parts appear error. Thanks.

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated and insecure mysql_ API

Comment: what's the error getting?

Comment: @ Strawberry  What your meaning?

Comment: @PHP Geek I have edited, you can see the error. Thanks.

Comment: check  your request object. it is not connecting with your server

Comment: I try to remove this code <htmlDetail>$product_description</htmlDetail> to become <htmlDetail>123</htmlDetail>, it is work. But if I put $product_description can't work.

Comment: mysql_query   was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0 https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @scaisEdge Ok Sir. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Yes  .. you should refactor you code using PDO or mysqli ...

Comment: @scaisEdge ok. Do you know why other variable coding can work, just $product_description can't work?

Comment: in your code  $product_description = $row['description'] is comment

Comment: I am using this "//" symbol is highlight where is it problem?